# Visual studio 2022 oracle database connection?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I'm trying to connect to an oracle database through visual studio 2022. Oracle developer tools for visual studio isn't out yet for version 2022. When using .NET framework data provider for oracle, I'm able to connect, but the database schema is made in such a way that all the tables are in database/Other Users/Shared. When connecting using .NET framework data providers fora oracle, it doesn't show the Other Users node I need to open. How can I connect to that node to call the stored procedure I need?

Comment: How are you planning to use this tool? Are you creating or editing table adapters?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to go to change view -> all objects

Comment: Please how did you connect to the oracle database using vs 2022 using EF?

Comment: I want to know how to connect to oracle database from visual studio 2022 using any method